# Selector - Temporarily disable an option while selected

Tags: javascript, selector

Is it possible to disable a select option while it is active? I have a selector which has various options that each trigger a SQL query. If the same option is selected twice, the map breaks. I thought the easiest solution for this would be to disable an option once it has been selected.

```
<select id="sql" onclick="updateSource()" class="selector"> 
    <option value="SELECT * FROM indicators WHERE 1=0" disabled selected>Select an Indicator</option>     
    <option value="SELECT * FROM indicators WHERE grain ILIKE 'Yes'">Change in grain (maize, wheat & barley) production</option>
    <option value="SELECT * FROM indicators WHERE sorghum ILIKE 'Yes'">Change in Sorghum production</option>
</select>
```

Comment: You want to disable select?

Comment: If you're using a back-end database, you *really* don't want to be exposing your SQL to the HTML source. If it's WebSQL, it's still not a great idea to muddy your presentation code (HTML) with business logic. Put it in an external JS file. This doesn't answer your question; it's just FYI.

Comment: @Utkanos Thanks for the advice, much appreciated. In this situation the back-end database is CartoDB, which is serving my map data that the SQL is querying. CartoDB gives you the ability to create a unique API using only the databases (map data layers) you need for the specific project, and also an option to set read permissions only. I would still much prefer to do this as you recommended, so it will definitely be something I will look into.

Comment: @AAShakil Yes, I want to disable a selected option (grey it out) so that it can not be clicked twice in a row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to disable an `option` once it gets selected?

```js
function updateSource(e) {
  const target = e[e.value];
  target.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="updateSource(this)">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an Indicator</option>
  <option value="1">Change in grain (maize, wheat & barley) production</option>
  <option value="2">Change in Sorghum production</option>
</select>
```

Or should it only disable the currently selected one?

```js
function updateSource(e) {
  Object.keys(e).forEach(k => e[k].disabled = false);
  const target = e[e.value];
  target.disabled = true;
}
```

```html
<select onchange="updateSource(this)">
  <option value="0" disabled selected>Select an Indicator</option>
  <option value="1">Change in grain (maize, wheat & barley) production</option>
  <option value="2">Change in Sorghum production</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for the examples, the second snippet is exactly what I was looking for.  However, in my application it is not working as there is also a onclick="updateSource()" function for the selector (I think that is the reason?). I have added a simplified example of my project to CodePen if you don't mind taking a look - https://codepen.io/JonoGIS/pen/vrexwp

Comment: @JohnGIS when working with select tags you usually don't need to listen to `onclick` events, `onchange` should be enought. Have you tried using it instead of `onclick`?

Comment: Is it possible to have two `onchange` listeners though? Because one is for the SQL function, and the other will be for the option disable. I am trying `onchange="updateSource();updateOptions(this)`, but the disable function isn't working.

Comment: why not just call `updateSource` from `updateOptions`?

Comment: @JohnGIS Otherwise if you really want to keep them 100% separate you can explicitly tell the browser to execute your "link" as js, like this: `onchange="javascript: console.log('Hello'); console.log('world!')"`

Comment: Actually, using `onchange` instead of `onclick` solved everything and no longer causes the crash! Thanks for all of your help, I also learnt something from your original post.

Comment: @JohnGIS Always glad to help :)